# How to use HttpGet Request in Android?

Tags: java, android, http, get

I am using this code, but it catches an error in a try-catch. Where is a mistake?

When I print a error, `content.setText(ex.getMessage());` is empty.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView content;
    EditText fname, email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        Button saveme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode("ffa", "UTF-8");
                    String fnameValue = URLEncoder.encode("fdsfdb", "UTF-8");

                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String URL = "http://mysite/app.php?a=" + loginValue + "&b=" + fnameValue;

                    try {
                        String SetServerString;
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                        content.setText(SetServerString);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        content.setText(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                    content.setText(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you are running network operation on the uithread

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get NetworkOnMainThreadException. You should perform network communication on background thread. Consider using IntentService or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I have same opinion with Nickolai.

**Work around:**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Use code above, only when you are writing code for yourself.

If your application are produced to others,you need a better way.

**Better way:**

You should use a handle to access http-request, [more info in developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use this myself:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
out.close();
String responseString = out.toString();
```