# Cannot connect to website

Tags: android

I am developing an app which require login of users. It is not working in Jelly Bean but working in GingerBread. Any Ideas?

Here is code.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.test;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String sname,spass;
    EditText sname1,spass1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        spass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sname   = sname1.getText().toString();
                spass   = spass1.getText().toString();

                BufferedReader reader=null;
                try
                    { 


                  String data= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("sname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sname, "UTF-8"); 
                  data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("spass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(spass, "UTF-8"); 


                  String text = null;
                  String temp1=null;

                  // Send data 



                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/login.php");

                  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                  wr.write(data); 
                  wr.flush(); 
                // Get the response 


                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;


                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    text = sb.toString();
                    temp1=text.trim();


                    if(temp1.contains("notequal"))
                     {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Code or Id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

                    else if(temp1.contains("equalto"))
                     {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
                     }


                    }

                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {

                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
                }

            }
        });//login



    }//oncreate
}//main
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Login" />
```

Here is login.php file:

```
<?php

   $sname   = urldecode($_POST['sname']);
   $spass   = urldecode($_POST['spass']);

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("paper");
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from student where name='$sname' and password='$spass'");
 if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 echo "equalto"; 

 }
else{
echo "notequal";}
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: its service u hv written right? its not like it will work with one version and dont with another version ...there must be different reason fot it.. did u use s ame credentials?...check logs from php from both the device

Comment: You access network on main thread. It's restricted on JB devices.Please, check following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083141/how-to-use-httpget-request-in-android/

Comment: I have developed a complete application based on this methodology i.e. Url object and using URLConnection conn etc. it is working well in gingerbread but not in jelly bean..

Comment: I have tried using AsyncTask as well . working in GingerBread but not in JellyBean.. I have made whole project from scratch using target version of jelly bean but no avail... should i mail my app to u if u give me ur mail id

Comment: Exception is java.net.socketException.. can anyone get it??

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89

Comment: From this website i have seen code

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution to your problem use AsyncTask for web request i have use HttpClient then HttpPost to make request on web.

//

new AsyncTask(){

```
                    @Override
                    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        try
                        {
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://182.188.140.167/gpsweb/check%20username.php");
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost); 
                            HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity();  
                            if (resEntityGet != null) 
                            { 
                                //Log.e("Checking responce", EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet).toString());
                                String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet).toString();
                                if(response1.contains("1"))
                                {
                                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GetLocation.class);
                                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                                    b.putString("uname",uname);
                                    i.putExtras(b);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        return 2;
                    }
```

Comment: still not working.. saying error java.net.socketException Permission Denied

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add the appropriate permission go your Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: No. Ihave added that permission already. If that was not the case it would not be running on gingerbread